# cat command: stdin redirection not working when used along with a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cat

I don't understand, while following cat command doesn't display contents of both file1.txt and file2.txt

```
cat file1.txt < file2.txt
```

It's displaying contents of file1.txt, but not the contents of file2.txt

while the following commands work as expected

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt
cat < file2.txt
```

Appreciate your help, in understanding the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write it as follows

```
$ cat file1.txt - < file2.txt
```

if you want to mix file arguments with stdin.

Source `man cat`, Examples.

Comment: thanks @ThorX89.  I had gone through the man page, but it wasn't obvious to me. The only example in man page with stdin was "cat f - g". Any reason why cat need this special '-' for stdin redirection?

Comment: I can only guess. If it didn't work like that and stdin were hardcoded to be the implicit first or the last file in the concatenation list, you'd still need an option to override the default if you wanted to place it somewhere else. Using a placeholder such as '-' solves the problem perfectly, and typing '-' is not really that much work as to warrant an implicit default.